# Restful Url pattern

Tags: api, http, url, rest, permalinks

Assume I have a url as the following, e.g.

1. http://www.company.com/categories # List all categories
2. http://www.company.com/categories/car # List all cars
3. http://www.company.com/products/303 # A car with unique id = 303

My question is, for 2. `http://www.company.com/categories/car`, is a better if I use its plural form?

e.g.

```
http://www.company.com/categories/cars
```

Comment: Define "better" - better for who/what purpose?

Comment: @Widor, I mean more standard and hence Restful

Comment: Is this a code-related issue at all? If I understand your question correctly, it seems not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make **2.** more of a RESTful pattern, you'd be issuing a `GET` request to retrieve the list of cars.

In that case, it would make sense to use the plural:

```
http://www.company.com/categories/cars
```

which leaves open the possibility to extend it with specific (singular) car records:

```
http://www.company.com/categories/cars/ferrari
```

Comment: You made a good point! So, why not http://www.company.com/categories/cars/ferraris? If I have further categories such as Luxury, Coupe etc. Seems to me that if a category does not have further sub categories, singular also make sense, but since we cannot predict the future, so always plural is more flexible.

Comment: Well, if you wanted to have _Ferraris_ as a category of car and have many models returned then you could pluralise it and that would still make sense. But for anything that only ever returns a single record (_Person_ would be a better example of this) then stick to singular.

Answer (score 5):

It's correct if you use plural for your resources. However, it's not called Restful if you use the url like that:

```
 http://www.company.com/categories/cars
```

because cars is the subresource of categories... So to be better, I suggest you should expose your cars resources as subresource of a specifice category:

```
 http://www.company.com/categories/123/cars #get all cars under category which id = 123
```

Comment: Isn't this what query strings were designed for?  i.e. `GET http://www.company.com/cars?category_id=123  # get all cars with category id = 123`.

Comment: Yes, you can use that either. However, the question above didn't talk about query string.

Answer (score 0):

It totally depended on you and your application. If you have a number of REST services you can also use carList instead of car or cars. That makes sense and less confusion. Be sure to be uniform in all your REST URIs.

Answer (score 0):

think of it as a Windows Explorer Directory. Where would a ferrari be if you were organising cars in a local folder?

Another thing to consider is to design URI specially for PUT and POST requests where you have more nouns and less verbs.

Answer (score 0):

**Plural**. The "cars" element in the url should reflect the name of the category. The name of categories are in my experience usually plural since they identify a set of multiple entities. E.g.: category of transporation devices are: cars, planes, bicycles and skateboards.

Something is a car and it belongs to the category "cars".

Nice example is the naming convention at wikipedia for set categories:

> Set categories are named after a class (usually in the plural). For example, Category:Cities in France contains articles whose subjects are cities in France.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Set_category#Set_category

Answer (score 0):

A category englobes a lot of items. So, yes. **Cars** would have more sense than **car**

```
http://www.company.com/categories/cars/mitsubishi/lancer (if you have more categories)
```

OR

```
http://www.company.com/categories/cars/lancer
```